# Django APIView.throttle_scope attribute doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, throttling

#### The problem

I was trying to implement throttling following the django rest framework [guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#scopedratethrottle). Since I don't need to create another throttle class, I tried to use the .throttle_scope attribute. So, I implemented it like this:

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    throttle_scope = 'my_scope'

    def post(self, request) -> Response:
        # do something
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And in the settings I wrote something like this:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'my_scope': '1/minute',
    }
}
```

---

#### What I tried

I tried, using postman, to make more than 1 request per minute to that endpoint and I never received a [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) code. Than I tried creating a new throttle class and using the .throttle_classes attribute, like this:

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = [MyThrottle]

    def post(self, request) -> Response:
        # do something
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```py
class MyThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'my_scope'
```

I left the settings unchanged and it worked as expected.

---

#### Possible cause

So now I'm wondering, could it be that the throttling_scope attribute only works if the user is anonymous?

I'm doing this assumption because I tried to make MyThrottle to inherit from `AnonRateThrottle` instead of `UserRateThrottle` and it didn't work. By the way, all the users who have access to this endpoint are all authenticated, thus I thought that `ScopedRateThrottle` is more like `AnonRateThrottle`.

Comment: did you add ScopedRateThrottle class to throttle_classes?

Comment: @iklinac no, because there should be no need for it, as the documentation also says. But thanks to you, I realized that I forgot to put the `ScopedRateThrottle` in `REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES']`.  With this I solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was trivial, and I solved it by adding `ScopedRateThrottle` inside:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        ...
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle'
    ],
    ...
}
```

I tested again and the problem was solved.